# How to run code when a TFrame is created?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, frame, delphi-11-alexandria, tframe

I need to run code when a `TFrame` is created, not when the frame shows, or when the parent form is created. I don't see any event handler for `OnCreate` for my `TFrame`.

How would one then be able to run code when a frame is created?

I am using Delphi 11.3 and my project is using FMX (Firemonkey)

Comment: Simply `override` the virtual [`Create()` constructor](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Forms.TFrame.Create) or virtual [`AfterConstruction()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Forms.TFrame.AfterConstruction) method. Not everything in Delphi is event-oriented

Answer (score 1):

Simply `override` the virtual [`Create() constructor`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Athens/en/FMX.Forms.TFrame.Create) or virtual [`AfterConstruction()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Forms.TFrame.AfterConstruction) method.

To `override` the `Create() constructor`, add `constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;` into your frame's private declarations and then press `Ctrl+Shift+C` to create the constructor below. It should create something like this:

```
constructor TMyFrame.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  // Your code goes here that runs when the frame is created
end;
```